# Python: Dict for counting unique letters in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using the String library in Python 3 to solve this HarvardX challenge, up to a point, but I don't think my solution is very good. Can you see a neater solution?

Here's my code:

```
#writing the 2 strings

alpha = string.ascii_letters

alpha
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

sent = 'She sells seashells on the seashore the seashells she sells are      seashells for sure'
sent
'She sells seashells on the seashore the seashells she sells are seashells for sure'

#WRITING DICT to lookup count alpha string characters within 'She sells(etc)'

mydict_countalpha = {alpha[0]:sent.count(alpha[0]), alpha[1]:sent.count(alpha[1]), alpha[2]:sent.count(alpha[2]), alpha[3]:sent.count(alpha[3]), alpha[4]:sent.count(alpha[4]), alpha[5]:sent.count(alpha[5])}

#result:
mydict_countalpha
{'a': 5, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 16, 'f': 1}
```

YAY. It counts correctly.

## Problem though

The alpha string is **52 characters long**. I think I'll make mistakes if I write this dictionary manually, line by line. How can I do this better? Is it something to do with iteration?

## Why I ask

This is based on a homework assignment for the excellent HarvardX course '[Using Python for Research](https://www.edx.org/course/using-python-for-research)'. It's assessed, but consulting Stack Overflow to figure it out is OK according to HarvardX guidance. :-) I'm not cheating by asking, if you have any ideas.

I think this challenge has very broad application & hope you also find it interesting. But, I'm a beginner programmer on a steep learning curve with Python. Thanks for any suggestions, though!

Best

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension

```
mydict_countalpha = {alpha[x]:sent.count(alpha[x]) for x in range(len(alpha))}
```

But there is no need to keep looking up the index. Loop over `alpha` directly

```
mydict_countalpha = {ch:sent.count(ch) for ch in alpha}
```

The way I would normally do this, however, is using collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
mydict_countalpha = {k: v for k, v in Counter(sent).items() if k in alpha}
```

**edit:** added for loop version

```
mydict_countalpha = {}
for ch in alpha:
    mydict_countalpha[ch] = sent.count(ch)
```

Comment: Cool! Using a dictionary comprehension DOES come up with the correct answer, but nevertheless I don't get marks for that. HarvardX are looking for me to use a For loop. Something more along the lines of what Adam did... I'll try to tick the right boxes.

Comment: They didn't say to use a For loop in the question. Kind of annoying, that.

Comment: @avwinter, I added a for loop version. The main problem with this approach is that `sent.count` scans through the whole string over and over (once for each character in alpha). It is more readable for a beginner than using `defaultdict` or `setdefault` though

Answer (score 3):

The Pythonic approach is to use `collections.Counter` and filter keys for `ascii_letters` via a dictionary comprehension. For efficiency, you can convert `ascii_letters` to a `set` first:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

letters_set = set(ascii_letters)

res = {k: v for k, v in Counter(sent).items() if k in letters_set}

print(res)

{'S': 1, 'h': 8, 'e': 16, 's': 17, 'l': 10, 'a': 5,
 'o': 3, 'n': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 4, 'f': 1, 'u': 1}
```

This solution has O(*m* + *n*) complexity, while your current solution has complexity O(*m* * *n*). You can appreciate this by understanding that `str.count`, like `list.count`, has O(n) complexity, i.e. each iteration within your dictionary comprehension requires a full parse of your string.

Answer (score 2):

It seems much easier to simply look at each letter in `sent` and increment the count for that letter each time.

```
my_dict = {}

for lett in sent:
    if lett in my_dict:
        my_dict[lett] += 1
    else:
        # first entry
        my_dict[lett] = 1
```

Or more simply, using `dict.setdefault`:

```
for lett in sent:
    my_dict.setdefault(lett, 0) += 1
```

However note that the stdlib module `collections` has an object called a `Counter` that does exactly this.

```
from collections import Counter

my_dict = Counter(sent)
```

---

You can further filter out unwanted letters before counting them with `filter`

```
alpha = set(string.ascii_letters)

filtered = filter(lambda ch: ch in alpha, sent)

my_dict = Counter(filtered)
```

Comment: This would also count those characters which are not in the `alpha` string, you need to filter those characters out somehow...

Comment: @JoeIddon is that part of the spec? I thought that was an accidental limitation on the part of the OP (but I admittedly haven't followed the link to the spec)

Comment: Oh fair enough could be either way :) I'm sure the OP will understand both ways anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict-comprehension:

```
mydict_countalpha = {c:sent.count(c) for c in alpha}
```

But it would be more efficient to use a `Counter` object as this current solution is `O(n^2)` whereas a `Counter` object is `O(n)` complexity to create and then we can filter out those which are not in the `alpha` string.

```
from collections import Counter
mydict_countalpha = {k:v for k,v in Counter(sent).items() if k in alpha}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of comments on the Edx discussion forum from other HarvardX students who tried different methods (including for loops, or comprehensions) to code for a correct answer but still couldn't pick up the points. Same here!

Below is the method beginners should use according to this course. I've adjusted slightly here so that any students browsing this still have to write their own code to pass...

```
sentenceA = 'I could not collect points on this homework and that is sad'
alphabet_string = string.ascii_letters
count_lett_dict = {}
for letters in sentenceA:
    if letters in alphabet_string:
        if letters in count_lett_dict:
            count_lett_dict[letters] += 1
        else:
            count_lett_dict[letters] = 1
count_lett_dict
```